# Sending token query string parameter from webpage url in POST request

Tags: php, http, post, request, token

I'm trying to send a POST request with part of the webpage URL as the parameter. For instance, in this url:

http://testsite.com/confirmEmail/?token=abcdefg

I want to be able to send the input token with the value abcdefg. I want to make this responsive to different token values. Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: The url your showing is an example of  GET request. Post is done on form submission and is never included inside the URL.

However if your trying to add the value 'abcdefg' to a form then access the GET from the URL like this:
$_GET[token]

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: So you're saying to pull the token value out of the url I need to do a GET request, and that it's impossible to do with a POST request? edit:thanks

Comment: Post and Get are seperate from eachother, Post is a form submission and Get is passed via URL

http://www.diffen.com/difference/GET_%28HTTP%29_vs_POST_%28HTTP%29

Comment: I think i'm confused. I don't want to pass the token value through the url, I want to pull it from the url and send it via POST through a form

Comment: I think that's pretty normal for this situation, you're confirming their email via email so they are just getting a link and you need to take it from there.

Comment: The Answer by @RightClick has a good example, you need to set the Get Request inside the form so that it can be sumbitted via Post

Comment: ok thanks guys. but do i put <?php $token=$_GET['token']; ?> inside or outside the POST form? The example below has it outside, but then how will the pulled values be responsively placed as the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is assuming they will do some action on this page, otherwise you would want a redirect.

```
<?php

$token=$_GET['token'];

?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo htmlentities($token, ENT_QUOTES);?>" />
<!--other form fields and submit button here-->
</form>
```

UPDATE:
This was a simple answer, to be easily understood, but of course echoing out a get variable straight from the url opens you up to xss.  Someone edited my answer to strip quotes from that variable but `htmlentities()` is also vulnerable to xss.  I believe the appropriate function nowadays is `htmlspecialchars($token, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")`.  If you go this route, you need to be careful about which encoding & characters you put in your tokens now, so they aren't stripped, which would probably break your verification process.  Looks like it's numeric in the example, so you should be ok.  Also remember someone could still post a modified form, so you need to sanitize this token field to prevent injections, but hopefully that's not relevant to this question.

Comment: So I have a form sending email and password values via a POST request already. If I add this token input to the exisiting form, will it send it via the form POST?

Comment: yes, you just pick up the value using `$_GET[]` (you may want to have an if statement using `isset()` on that value just in case)  And then you can insert it as a hidden input in your form, as long as the form method is POST, the entire form and all inputs will be sent as POST

Comment: btw, depending on what browser you use, you can press F12 to launch the developer tools, and use the "Network" tab to monitor all of the requests your browser makes.  So you can use that to confirm that your form passes on that hidden input.  That's helpful with multi-part problems like this, so you can eliminate issues as you move through the flow and debug.

Comment: do i put <?php $token=$_GET['token']; ?> inside or outside the POST form? The example you provided has it outside, but then how will the pulled values be responsively placed as the value for the form POST?

Comment: I've tried both ways and neither is responsivelt pulling the value from the url. However, adding the hidden token input into the form now shows Token as a parameter. So that worked

Comment: it just needs to be above (before) the form.  All it does is assign the value to a variable.  if you wanted to be really minimalist, you could echo it in the form without ever assigning it to a `$token` variable by replacing `<?php echo $token;?>` with `<?php echo $_GET['token'];?>`   This is just example code, but I would usually have some validation when I pick up the value with `if(isset($_GET['token']))` and some way of validating the value before I do anything with it, and then in my else clause tell them their link was invalid because it doesn't contain the token.

Comment: try putting `<?php echo $_GET['token'];?>` somewhere on the page where you can see it.  If you can echo it at all, you will be able to do so in the value of that hidden form input.

Comment: Hmm...well now I'm getting my token value to just be that string of code. This is what my server is getting:
Token: <?php echo $_GET['token'];?>

As if its never gettting the value from the GET request

Comment: what happens if you just put `<?php echo "hello world";?>` somewhere on your page? Do you see the `hello world` output from php, or do you see the entire `<?php echo "hello world";?>` on the page?

Comment: Maybe I should've mentioned this is an HTML file not a .php file. When I put <?php echo "hello world";?> anywhere on the page literally nothing happend. I put it in a few different divs without an effect

Comment: ok, you tagged this question with `php` so I assumed you wanted a php approach.  html files are static, so you aren't going to be able to do dynamic things like this.   If you are really limited to something static, you can use javascript to pick up the value from the url and put it into the hidden form input.  So very similar to this approach, just that instead of your server sending the form with the value in it, your server will send the form without that and their browser will do it on the client side.

Comment: Yea sorry about that. Couldn't I just save this .html file as a .php file and get the same result?

Comment: assuming your server has php, yes.  Changing the extension to .php should make this work

Comment: Yes. I've made it a .php file and still the same result. Also placeing <?php echo "hello world";?> still results in nothing.

Comment: what do you mean by nothing?  When you view the page source and inspect the html, nothing is output?

Comment: As in nothing appears on the page. this shows up inside inspect element 

<!--?php echo "hello world";?-->

Comment: inspect element doesn't always show the raw html output.  use ctrl+u and then you can use ctrl+f to find "hello world", what is the actual raw html output?  It sounds like your server won't run php.  What is this running on?

Comment: Following your instructions shows <?php echo "hello world";?> as the raw output. It is linux server, redhat style

Comment: install php on it, or edit your configuration.  If you can't echo a string then you're out of luck

Comment: Yep. Just needed to edit the configuration. Thanks so much for sticking with me

Comment: Added the htmlentities filter, because when you directly output user porvided content in an HTML thing, it should not contain any HTML...